# Синглтон для потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность

В `c++` есть спицификатор `thread_local` который позволяет привязать переменную к потоку. В одной из моих программ я использую данный спецификатор для подобия синглтона, который возвращает некий объект (который не может быть разделен между потоками, но могут быть инстансы для каждого потока) конкретно для использования в потоке из которого произошел вызов функции. Примерно так:

```cpp
class ThreadSingleton {
  public:
    static Object &instance() {
      thread_local Object retval;
      return retval;
    }

  ...
};

...

// in thread1
auto &instanceForThread1 = ThreadSingleton::instance();

... 
// in thread2
auto &instanceForThread2 = ThreadSingleton::instance();
```

Таким образом, по логике, при первом вызове из нового потока будет создана новая переменная, когда будет возвращаться при последующих вызовах из этого потока.

С проблемами я не сталкивался используя такой подход, но решил всё-таки уточнить: есть ли сдесь подводные камни?

Comment: у переменной и функции одинаковое имя......

Comment: @Данил подправил

Comment: Ваш пример не может не  вызывать вопрос:  " А причем тут синглтон?"

Comment: подразумевая, что конструктор копирования запретил и обычный конструктор сделал приватным/защищённым, в остальном вроде бы всё в порядке... но, на правах вкусовщины, я бы предпочёл синглтона на основе указателя...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan конструкция аналогичная синглтону Майерса за тем исключением того, что вместо static используется thread_local

Comment: Из подводных камней вы можете столкнуться с тем, что ваш синглтон будет владеть какими-либо эксклюзивными ресурсами (файл/сокет/...), тогда при порождении нескольких потоков, будет создано несколько ваших объектов, но владеть ресурсом сможет только один, также может быть проблема синхронизации состояния (например синглтон хранит настройки и записывает их в файл, при создании Н потоков, может быть логическое рассогласование данных)

Comment: @goldstar_labs по поводу создания нескольких объектов для каждого потока - в этом и цель, так как объекты не могут быть разделены между потоками. Что касается синхронизации, то это не требуется

Comment: тогда это собственно целевое использование thread_local  =)